# Non-cyclic tmux pane selection

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

When I'm in a multi-pane tmux window, on the leftmost pane, pressing my shortcut to move to the pane to the left will cyclically move the focus to the rightmost pane. I would prefer this shortcut to take no action in this case, i.e., to stay in the already selected leftmost pane.

I read the [man page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1). There is also a chapter about [pane traversal](https://leanpub.com/the-tao-of-tmux/read#pane-traversal) in the The Tao of Tmux book, but this is not mentioned.

The `select-pane` command in tmux has a lot of switches, but they are not documented:

```
$ tmux select-pane --help
usage: select-pane [-DdegLlMmRU] [-P style] [-T title] [-t target-pane]
```

In case it's relevant, my shortcuts to select the panes are as follows:

```
bind -n C-M-h select-pane -L
bind -n C-M-j select-pane -D
bind -n C-M-k select-pane -U
bind -n C-M-l select-pane -R
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy with `pane_at_left`, `pane_at_right`, `pane_at_top` and `pane_at_bottom` formats.

```
bind -n C-M-h if-shell -bF '#{pane_at_left}'   '' 'select-pane -L'
bind -n C-M-j if-shell -bF '#{pane_at_bottom}' '' 'select-pane -D'
bind -n C-M-k if-shell -bF '#{pane_at_top}'    '' 'select-pane -U'
bind -n C-M-l if-shell -bF '#{pane_at_right}'  '' 'select-pane -R'
```

---

These formats were introduced in tmux 2.6. In prior versions you can still get the same effect by running scripts (`run-shell`) that retrieve `window_width`, `window_height`, `pane_left`, `pane_right`, `pane_top` and `pane_bottom` from tmux (`tmux display -p …`), perform calculations and comparison, and decide to cast `tmux select-pane …` or not.

Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1489555/432690). The script there could use the new formats in few places. I needed the other values anyway, so I decided to keep the script compatible with older tmux.