# Clockwise pane numbering on split

Tags: tmux

The behavior of how tmux numbers the panes seems to follow that leftmost and topmost gets the least numbers, with that priority respectively

For instance, if I vertically split the left window in below configuration:

[image: before]

I get this

[image: after]

Is there any way I could enforce numbering to be clockwise? i.e.

```
0   1
3   2
```

My main objective is to use <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> to cycle through panes in a clockwise manner. Numbering the panes in a clockwise manner seems to be one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I could enforce numbering to be clockwise?

I am now aware of any such way.

---

> My main objective is to use <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> to cycle through panes in a clockwise manner.

This can be done with a script that identifies the desired pane and selects it. Save the below code under the name `_tmux-cycle-clockwise` in some directory where your `PATH` points to.

```
#!/bin/sh

countercl=0
[ "$1" = '-c' ] && countercl=1

# This function reads geometry from tmux and sets variables.
read_geometry () {
   geometry="$(tmux display-message -p -F '#{window_width} #{window_height} #{pane_left} #{pane_right} #{pane_top} #{pane_bottom}')" || return 1

   ww="${geometry%% *}"
   geometry="${geometry#* }"
   wh="${geometry%% *}"
   geometry="${geometry#* }"
   pl="${geometry%% *}"
   geometry="${geometry#* }"
   pr="${geometry%% *}"
   geometry="${geometry#* }"
   pt="${geometry%% *}"
   pb="${geometry#* }"
}

# This function finds neighbor pane
find_neighbor () {
   panes="$(tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_left} #{pane_right} #{pane_top} #{pane_bottom} #{pane_id}')"
   if [ "$countercl" -eq 0 ]; then
      if [ "$pt" -eq 0 ] && [ "$pr" -ne "$((ww-1))" ]; then
         pattern="^$((pr+2)) .* 0 .* .*$"
      elif [ "$pr" -eq "$((ww-1))" ] && [ "$pb" -ne "$((wh-1))" ]; then
         pattern="^.* $((ww-1)) $((pb+2)) .* .*$"
      elif [ "$pb" -eq "$((wh-1))" ] && [ "$pl" -ne 0 ]; then
         pattern="^.* $((pl-2)) .* $((wh-1)) .*$"
      elif [ "$pl" -eq 0 ] && [ "$pt" -ne 0 ]; then
         pattern="^0 .* .* $((pt-2)) .*$"
      else
         printf ':.+'
         return
      fi
   else
      if [ "$pr" -eq "$((ww-1))" ] && [ "$pt" -ne 0 ]; then
         pattern="^.* $((ww-1)) .* $((pt-2)) .*$"
      elif [ "$pt" -eq 0 ] && [ "$pl" -ne 0 ]; then
         pattern="^.* $((pl-2)) 0 .* .*$"
      elif [ "$pl" -eq 0 ] && [ "$pb" -ne "$((wh-1))" ]; then
         pattern="^0 .* $((pb+2)) .* .*$"
      elif [ "$pb" -eq "$((wh-1))" ] && [ "$pr" -ne "$((ww-1))" ]; then
         pattern="^$((pr+2)) .* .* $((wh-1)) .*$"
      else
         printf ':.-'
         return
      fi
   fi
   printf '%s\n' "$panes" | grep "$pattern" | cut -d ' ' -f 5
}

main () {
   newp=""
   read_geometry
   newp="$(find_neighbor)"
   tmux select-pane -t "$newp" || exit 1
}

main
```

Next add these lines to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -T prefix o run-shell '_tmux-cycle-clockwise'
bind-key -T prefix a run-shell '_tmux-cycle-clockwise -c'
```

Restart your tmux server (or reload the file: <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Now <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> will cycle through panes in a clockwise manner; <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> will cycle counterclockwise.

Notes:

- The script calls `tmux` few times. If the current window changes or panes change in the meantime, the script may work erroneously.
- "Counterclockwise" does not undo "clockwise"; "clockwise" does not undo "counterclockwise". There are at least two reasons:

  - In general the script doesn't cycle through all panes, it cycles through border panes. It can leave a non-border pane to a border or non-border pane; but from a border pane it will never enter a non-border pane.
  - The next pane in cycle is determined only by the current pane, not by its edge. This is relevant e.g. for this layout:

    ```
    0 |   | 3
    --| 2 |--
    1 |   | 4
    ```

    In theory you can go from `2` clockwise to `3` along the top edge or clockwise to `1` along the bottom edge. The script always goes to `3`, so its clockwise cycle is `2-3-4-2-3-4-…`. However its counterclockwise cycle is `2-0-1-2-0-1-…`. This is by design. This way you can reach more border panes solely with the script somehow. Still there are layouts where some border panes are unreachable for the script. Example:

    ```
    0 |   | 3 |   | 6
    --| 2 |---| 5 |--
    1 |   | 4 |   | 7
    ```

    From `2` you can't get to `4` solely with the script.

    This could be fixed if tmux could identify the last pane for me (like it can identify the last window). I think it can't. Another way would be to store information from one invocation of the script to the next, per tmux window. I chose not to implement this.